# Textfield won't pass text to console in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

Am trying to get a textfield to capture text input, and pass the output (entered by the user) to console.

Here is the method:

```
- (IBAction)done
{
    NSLog(@"Contents of the text field: %@", self.textField);
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Strange thing is the output I'm getting in the console is:

```
Checklists[3870:70b] Contents of the text field: <UITableViewCell: 0x8c88f00; frame = (0 35; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x8c89090>>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: use self.textField.text

Comment: According to the output, `self.textField` is actually a `UITableViewCell`, not a `UITextField`. You have something setup incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you, found the problem. Had selected the cell instead of the textField. Once I fixed that, everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `text` field of the `textField` instance.

`NSLog(@"Contents of the text field: %@", [[self.textField] getText]);`

Look at this other SO question: [How to get a Text Field's text in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086105/how-to-get-a-text-fields-text-in-xcode)

Comment: Thank you. Problem is that when I write "self.textField.text", I get a warning that "text is deprecated. First deprecated in iOS 3.0" When I ran the code, I got NULL instead of the input text. Any idea why?

Comment: Try this `[[self.textField] getText]`.